# Проверка параметров в цикле

Tags: python, циклы, selenium

Хочу сделать проверку по графе Payment (см скриншот ниже). Если из "моего" списка вариантов нет, то проверка осуществляется по следующему div-у и т.д. до момента когда есть совпадение. Пока понял как сделать цикл, но он выдает просто все результаты, без проверки.
Вот код:

```
i = [] 
Banks = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[@class="css-ovjtyv"]').text 
for i in range(2):
    containers = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//div[@class="css-vurnku"]')
    Banks = containers[i].find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[@class="css-ovjtyv"]//ancestor::div[1]').text
    print(Banks)
```

Подскажите, как мне в этот цикл (если он вообще верный) добавить нужную проверку?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

на пример

```
if Banks == "Рога и копыта":
    print(Banks)
```